# can Apache Ignite near cache be off-heap?

Tags: ignite

the docs says "Near caches store data in the on-heap memory. ",
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.15.0/configuring-caches/near-cache
but I know we can configure a cache being on-heap/off-heap, just not sure if it applies to near cache too.

> CacheConfiguration.setOnheapCacheEnabled(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No is the short answer. A near cache is always on-heap.

I should also add that setOnHeapCacheEnabled does not configure whether a cache is on- or off-heap. An Ignite cache is *always* off-heap. An on-heap cache is *in addition* to the off-heap cache.